# IE 11 doesn't print page until new tab is opened

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-11

We have a website that prints out documents on a button click, then once the script to hide the button and print has executed, the system moves on to the next page.

However a number of customers using IE11 are reporting that when they click Print, the print button disappears (which is by design / script), however the print dialog does not open up.

But if they open up a new tab, then the Print Dialog opens up and the page redirects to the next page in the sequence.

This does not happen to all users of IE11, just a few isolated cases. And the system works fine in all other versions of IE.

I have tried switching compatibility mode on / off, and changing security settings but I can't duplicate this.

I know it's bad form to ask open ended questions, but I'm at my wits end. Anyone know how to fix this issue, or at least narrow down what may be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Get one of the affected computers and try it as another user, try IE in safe mode, try with the OS in Safe mode, etc.

Basically you're aiming to determine if it's a plug-in or some kind of 3rd-party app that's the problem... Perhaps even the print driver on those computers.

Comment: Thanks. Might have to find one with a technical user on site who can do that via 'remote control', or one that will let me install teamviewer on tier pc for an hour or 2. the fact that you didnt say "Its X" tells me that this isn't an obvious one anyway :-)